# Algorithm calculation time issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am performing a classification process on Apache Spark. For example I used the Random Forest algorithm on my data set. How can I learn the computation time of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend put like that

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
// this is where you are fitting your df and saving the model
val pred=model.transform(<DF>) 
val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("Total Time taken " endTime-startTime)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is fit? Or 
 transform(Data)?

Answer (score 0):

I would put an action (e.g. count(), write()) at the end of the algorithm, the time from beginning to the end of the action is roughly the time of running the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When using the algorithm in the Classification process, do I have to terminate the timer when fitting or transforming.